# Child not moving with Parent Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Player Object which performs an animation for entering the car and after completion of this animation, I'm calling a function SettoParent() using animationEvent, which works perfectly.

The Player Object has to be set as a child to the Car Object, which is working perfectly.

But when I drive the car, the player does not move together with the car.

The function `SetToParent()` is attached to the Player Object

I have used the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SettingParent : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform parent;
    public Transform child;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void SetToParent(){

        child.transform.parent = parent.transform;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do they have rigidbodies?

Comment: Where are you attaching the script `SettingParent`?

Comment: Both of them having rigidbodies and the script is attached to the Player Object.

Comment: I see some corrections here. First of all your script should be attached to your `FullPlayerObject` in order to move the entire `Player` with the `CameraRig` etc.. Second, your method `SetToParent()` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `child` and `parent` variables are already `transform`s, so you can use them as follows -

```
public void SetToParent(){
    child.parent = parent;
}
```

In inspector set the `parent` to `Car` and `child` to `Player/FullPlayerObject`.